# ElasticSearch to MS SQL Server

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

We are having daily indexes created for internal application monitoring. We receive close to 0.3 million records for day and the same is being analyzed real time using Kibana.

Now we want to move data from elasticsearch to MSSQL Server. Using nodejs elasticsearch module , I am able to move the data into the MSSQL Server.

However , it can be done for a small volume around 1000 records . As I want to read all the records from elasticsearch and dump it into MSSQL server, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the same using elasticsearch scroll capability. Refer the link for more information
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-2-2.html#api-scroll-2-2

Sample code here in case link becomes inactive

```
var allTitles = [];

// first we do a search, and specify a scroll timeout
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  // Set to 30 seconds because we are calling right back
  scroll: '30s',
  search_type: 'scan',
  fields: ['title'],
  q: 'title:test'
}, function getMoreUntilDone(error, response) {
  // collect the title from each response
  response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
    allTitles.push(hit.fields.title);
  });

  if (response.hits.total !== allTitles.length) {
    // now we can call scroll over and over
    client.scroll({
      scrollId: response._scroll_id,
      scroll: '30s'
    }, getMoreUntilDone);
  } else {
    console.log('every "test" title', allTitles);
  }
});
```